# Android 2.2: Problem playing video from SD card

Tags: android, android-videoview, lag

When I try to play a video on my sd card, i get the error message "Sorry, this video cannot be played". Is there anything wrong with my code? None of the commented code seems to work.

```
  public void PlayVideo(View view)
{       

VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);

mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
```

// final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/yu5.mp4");

```
//videoView.setVideoPath(MEDIA_PATH);

//videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"yu5.mp4")));

//videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/yu5.mp4"));

videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://www.law.duke.edu/cspd/contest/finalists/viewentry.php?file=mfog"));

videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

videoView.start();




}
```

When i stream from the web like in the code, the video is lagging a lot.

Comment: Here is another example.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083609/playing-video-from-sd-card

go get it.

Answer (score 4):

Please use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` for the root directory of external storage, not /sdcard, which is wrong on Android 2.2+ and other devices. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Media/Video) demonstrating playing back video from external storage.