# Playing video from Sd card

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have build an app that has videos in it that stream from the Internet and I'm not very impressed with the performance of them. Would anyone like to share the code for loading videos from the SD card.

Thanks

Comment: You wanna play videos from SD card, Right?
Its better if you share your part of code for understanding.

Comment: Go through the ApiDemo code, and set the path such as - /mnt/sdcard/<rest of location & filename>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this code help u

```
public class video extends Activity{

    VideoView video_view;
    String ex_name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.eccryption);
        video_view = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

        ex_name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("video_name");

        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(video_view);
        video_view.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);

    }

    Handler handler = new Handler(){

        public void handleMessage(Message msg){

            int pos=msg.what;
            if (pos == 1){

                video_view.setVideoPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+ex_name+".mp4");
                video_view.requestFocus();
                video_view.start();

                Log.d("Before Video Finish", "i m in before video finish");
                video_view.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
```

Use this Code This Code,My dear friends !

Answer (score 0):

Create an activity and call it when you need to play the video.
You can bundle the video path (whether url or sdcard or a resource) in the Intent.
Then in your activity which should only contain a `FrameLayout` with a `VideoView` do something like:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        mVideoPath = extras.getString(INTENT_EXTRA_URI);
        int resId = getResId(mVideoPath, R.raw.class);
                    String uriPath = null;
        if (mVideoPath.startsWith("http://") || mVideoPath.startsWith("https://")) {
            uriPath = mVideoPath;
        } else if (mVideoPatah.startsWith("/mnt/sdcard/")) {
            uriPath = mVideoPath;
        } else {
            int resId = getResId(mVideoPath, R.raw.class);
            uriPath = "android.resource://" + getResources().getResourcePackageName(resId) + "/" + resId;
        }
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uriPath));
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        mVideoView.requestFocus();
        mVideoView.start();         
    }
```