# how to play video from sdcard

Tags: android

i am doing on a project where i have numbers of product categories and each product category contains a single video.
i am playing video by getting url from web service. when first time i play that video it should download that video from that url only once. and when there is no internet connectivity it should play from where it is downloaded(sdcard). suppose i have downloaded 3 videos for all three products now i have to play those videos when there is no internet i.e. from sdcard. here comes problem that how to get particular video path for respective products. i don't have to open gallery. i have to directly play that video for that product. and how to restrict video downloading more then once.
my code for playing video is

```
    private void playVideo(String path) {

    dialog = new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_video_popup);

    ImageView imgViewClose = (ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.imgViewClose);
    imgViewClose.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnPlayPause = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnPlayPause.setOnClickListener(this);

    seekBar = (SeekBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    seekBar.setOnClickListener(this);
    linearlayout = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.linerlayout_bottom);
    mVideoView = (VideoView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    mVideoView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    dialog.show();

    playVideo(path, mVideoView);
    AppLog.d("Video", "playVideo()", path);


}

private void playVideo(String path, VideoView mVideoView) {
    if(path == null || path.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        pDialpg = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Video", "Please wait..", false, true);
        mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
        mVideoView.requestFocus();
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);  
        relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        mVideoView.setLayoutParams(relativeParams);
        mVideoView.invalidate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

Comment: Please refer to this Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083609/playing-video-from-sd-card

Comment: these provides link for specific video. my problem is something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just an example of how you could do it...

You can check if there's connection:

```
public Boolean checkConnectivity(Context context) {

    Log.d(TAG, "Checking connectivity");
    try {
        connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        wifiInfo = connectivityManager
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        mobileInfo = connectivityManager
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        if (wifiInfo.isConnected() || mobileInfo.isConnected()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Wifi/mobile Connection found");
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "PROBLEM " + e);
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "No connection found - working offline");
    return false;
}
```

First time, if no connection, you could set a default warning for example: "Can't play video without internet connection"

if there's conn. you could just play streaming like:

```
    public Void playVideoStream(Context context,
        String url, final VideoView videoView) {

    Log.d(TAG, "Playing video stream");

    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(context);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

    Uri video = Uri.parse(url);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);

    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            videoView.start();
        }
    });

    return null;
}
```

and if you have already downloaded it:

```
    public Void playVideoOffline(Context context,
        String filePath, VideoView videoView) {

    Log.d(TAG, "Playing video offline");

    videoView.setVideoPath(filePath);

    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(context);
    mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView);

    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.requestFocus();

    videoView.start();

    return null;
}
```

This is one way you could do it, not necessarily the best way of doing it.